# ASP.NET web.config transformation related on publish profile name

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have three publish profile on my ASP.NET MVC project.

[image]

I need to add transformations for all of them. For doing that, I picked "Add Config Transform" on web.config file and got 4 web configs:

[image]

But I can't understand how can I assign any of them to any publish profile. For example, I can't find the right config file for put transformation for development publish profile. How can I do that ? 
Thanks for any advice.

Comment: When publishing you choose your configuration you want to publish with, and it will choose the equivalent web config file.

Comment: @PaulKaram Thanks but I think I need to use "Release" configuration in all cases... So I think that is not a good solution...

Comment: Under your MVC project, expand Properties, and you'll find all your profiles under the PublishProfiles folder. You can edit the `mysite-environment - Web Deploy.pubxml` file directly. I think the line `<LastUsedBuildConfiguration>Release</LastUsedBuildConfiguration>` is what you want?

Comment: @neustart47, I think we are looking for the same solution here. You have solution configuration and related web.[SC].config transforms, but now you're looking to have a web.[SC].PublishProfile.config transform as well?  That's what I'm looking for.  Not sure if it's possible with Web.config as of now.  SlowCheeta makes it possible with *.configs... Gonna keep searching.

Comment: Looks like it should work... gonna test this solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31737080/relationship-between-solution-configuration-publish-profile-and-web-config-tra

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've created a new web config which I named "Web.development.config".
That's my project file code for transformations:

```
<UsingTask TaskName="TransformXml" AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.dll" />
<Target Name="AfterCompile" Condition="exists('Web.$(Configuration).config')">
  <!-- Generate transformed app config in the intermediate directory -->
  <TransformXml Source="Web.config" Destination="$(IntermediateOutputPath)$(TargetFileName).config" Transform="Web.$(Configuration).config" />
  <!-- Force build process to use the transformed configuration file from now on. -->
  <ItemGroup>
    <AppConfigWithTargetPath Remove="Web.config" />
    <AppConfigWithTargetPath Include="$(IntermediateOutputPath)$(TargetFileName).config">
      <TargetPath>$(TargetFileName).config</TargetPath>
    </AppConfigWithTargetPath>
  </ItemGroup>
</Target>
```

So with this solution you can use `Web.<your publish profile name>.config`

Comment: Thanks for taking time to leave this answer - helped me immensely.

Answer (score 2):

When you want to create a publish profile, you see a dropdown list where you specify what mode it will be. Try to create a new publish profile and you will see.

[image]